# Conditionally Select View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app that displays a login screen upon launching. To login a user, the app talks to a webapp. The settings for the app is where the webapp's url and other required information is specified.

I want the app to make sure all the required settings have been provided and are valid before displaying the login screen. If the settings are not complete, I want to notify the user that the settings need are incomplete.

I can modify the login view and add hidden error text and conditionally hide or show the error text and the login fields. But I would rather keep the error and login views separate.

This app uses xib files (no storyboard). It extends `UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>` and from what I can tell this is where the initial view controller for the app is being set (in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`).

I am thinking of creating a new view controller for the incomplete settings scenario and in the app delegate setting this as the initial view when the settings are incomplete.

Is there a better or standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our similar app, our initial view controller is a loading page (with `UIActivityIndicatorView` and title/logo). Our app makes initial communication with the server on this page.

If they've already logged in, we segue to the main view controller.

If the user isn't logged in (and it's okay to do so), we segue to the login view controller. Once they log in, we send them back to the beginning.

If there's an error, we show a `UIAlertView` and just send them back to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. I liked this scheme and I implemented my logic similarly. The root controller does the checks while showing a spinner and a message. I wanted to update the message at various steps of the checks, so I am running my checks in a separate thread. the thread calls a method on the root controller on main thread to update the message as each step is finished. Finally, if all is good, the thread calls a method on root controller on main thread to present the login view controller.

Answer (score 1):

My app uses a root view controller that sits above the login/home screens.  I check for a valid session in the root.  If there's a valid session, I push the home view controller on to the stack.  If there isn't a valid session, I push the login view controller on the stack.  You could take a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks. In what method of the root view controller do you do this?